# make and make otapackage

Tags: build, makefile, android-source

In AOSP development does `make otapackage` command do everyhing as `make` command with additionally creating .zip file? Reason I am asking is because right now for making `otapackage` I first execute `make` and than `make otapackage`, and I was wondering if first make is unnecessary?

I have found some posts but I am not 100% sure if I understood.

http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-building-android-from-source

> Running “make” will produce a basic, image based build, which is not
>   easily flashed to a device. Chances are, you want to build a
>   flash-able update.zip style file which can easily be installed to a
>   device. To do this, use the command “make otapackage” (for CyanogenMod
>   ROMs, “make bacon” is used instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to answer, `make otapackage` will do same thing as `make` just with additional of creating zip ota file.

Answer (score 5):

While `make` might be a subset of `make otapackage` *right now*, if this property is important to you I suggest you instead run `make droid otapackage`. The default goal of the Android build system is "droid", i.e. `make` and `make droid` are equivalent. Asking for both goals in the same invocation of make is more efficient than running `make` followed by `make otapackage` and is guaranteed to produce the results you're looking for.

(Unless, obviously, in the unlikely event that the default goal changes from "droid" to something else.)

Comment: So in Android 6, I see that make otapackage does not exist any more. Any idea how I can create a flashable zip file out of the compiled andorid?